# How can I "explode" a collection of collection of IDS into a single collection of DISTINCT IDS?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose I have this LINQ query (on .NET 4.0) :

```
IEnumerable<Service> listService = (from MyObject myObj in new MyObjects()
                                        select myObj.Services);
```

As you can see, `listService` is a collection of "collection" (`Services` is a collection of "Service", which contains a Title, an ID (what I need), and some other fields.).

What I'd like to do in LINQ is to have, with that query, an `IEnumerable<int>`, with the Distinct list of ID for each `Service` for each `Services`.

Is there a way to do this on LINQ or I need to cycle with some foreach and manage with another arrays?

Example :

```
my first myObj (so, MyObjects[0]) have got a collection, called Service, which contain single Service. Every Service have got a single id, respectively : "1", "2", "4"

my second myObj (so, MyObjects[1]) have got a collection, called Service, which contain single Service. Every Service have got a single id, respectively : "4", "5", "1", "2"}
```

What I need is a "single" collection which contains the list of ID from each Service collection from each myObj. This list must be with Distinct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't shown the content of your classes, I implemented what I could guess from your description. Does this match your objects?

```
class Service
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class MyObject
{
    public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }
}

class MyObjects : List<MyObject>
{

}
```

If so, then if I stick the following in the constructor for `MyObjects`:

```
class MyObjects : List<MyObject>
{
    public MyObjects()
    {
        Add(new MyObject 
            { 
                Services = new List<Service>()
                    {
                        new Service { ID = 1, Name = "foo" },
                        new Service { ID = 2, Name = "bar" },
                    }
            });
        Add(new MyObject
        {
            Services = new List<Service>()
                    {
                        new Service { ID = 3, Name = "baz" },
                        new Service { ID = 4, Name = "foo1" },
                        new Service { ID = 1, Name = "dup 1"}
                    }
        });
    }
}
```

I can get the distinct IDs like so:

```
var distinctIDs = (from myObj in new MyObjects()
               from service in myObj.Services
               select service.ID).Distinct();
```

The following test program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var objects = new MyObjects();
    var distinctIDs = (from myObj in new MyObjects()
                       from service in myObj.Services
                       select service.ID).Distinct();
    var notDistinctIDs = from myObj in new MyObjects()
                         from service in myObj.Services
                         select service.ID;
    foreach (var id in distinctIDs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Distinct ID: {0}", id);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("---");
    foreach (var id in notDistinctIDs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not Distinct ID: {0}", id);
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Distinct ID: 1
Distinct ID: 2
Distinct ID: 3
Distinct ID: 4
---
Not Distinct ID: 1
Not Distinct ID: 2
Not Distinct ID: 3
Not Distinct ID: 4
Not Distinct ID: 1
```

Comment: I don't think it will work, unfortunatly. It says : "Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'" on myObj.Services

Comment: @markzzz well, that means I did not correctly interpret how your classes look like. Try to type cast your myObj.Services call to whatever `IEnumerable<T>` it implements

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Updated assuming that initial query should *really* read something like:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> listService = ...;
```

Assuming you're just trying to flatten the results, it sounds like you may just want:

```
var results = listService.SelectMany(service => service)
                         .Distinct();
```

(If that's not what you're after, please clarify the question - it's fairly confusing at the moment.)

Comment: uhm, not really! Ids is not a collection of ID. service is the collection of Id. So I can't access to service.Ids

Comment: @markzzz: I'm currently finding your question *really* hard to understand. A short but complete example would have made it much clearer. You claim you've got an `IEnumerable<ListService>` but we have no idea what's in there. If you can clarify your question, I'm sure we can help you - but at the moment I'm lost.

Comment: Hope the example insterted is more clear now! Else let me know, I'll try to improve :)

Comment: @markzzz: It's not much clearer, to be honest - your initial query still talks about a `ListService` type. Does that type even exist, or does `Services` just return a collection of ints?

Comment: "Services just return a collection of ints?". Yes. But is wrote in my first line : "Services is a collection of IDS"

Comment: @markzzz: But you *also* wrote that your query returns an `IEnumerable<ListService>`. This is why it's so hard to understand your question - it's incredibly inconsistent.

Comment: Yeah, to be honest Services is not really a real collection of IDS. Is a collection of `Service`, which, for each Service, I have a Title, an ID (what I need) and some other data.

Comment: @markzzz: Right, so you were being inconsistent *and* inaccurate before. Can you see why this makes it hard to answer? It's still really unclear where everything goes - a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would make this feasible to answer, but until then there's nothing I can do.

Comment: @markzzz: It's still not clear - does the `MyObject.Services` property return a single `Service` or multiple? If it's the latter, your question is still broken. Once again, if you could actually show this in full code, there'd be no need to interpret. *Please* just put together a short but complete program.

Answer (score 1):

In query syntax:

```
IEnumerable<int> listService = (
       from MyObject myObj in new MyObjects()
       from id in myObj.Services).Distinct();
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this...but that's another LINQ query! I'd like to do it in one :)

Comment: @markzzz: I must agree, your question is hard to understand. Two LINQ queries does not mean that it takes more time to execute than one since LINQ is lazely evaluated with `IEnumerable<T>`. I have shown you how to get all distinct IDs of all services of all objects. What else do you need to know?

Comment: And in fact no, this query don't do what I need. obj.Services? obj is a Service...

Comment: @markzzz: Edited my answer. But you should really show us next time your classes. You're saying that _"Service contains these ids"_. But **is** (inherits) service an `int`-collection or **has** (property) it one?

Comment: :O `Services` is a collection (I wrote this). .Distinct doesnt works in that example...I don't want the distinct collections, but the distinct list of ids for each Services collections...